# Mapping a list to a Huffman Tree whilst preserving relative order

Tags: python, data-structures, huffman-code

I'm having an issue with a search algorithm over a Huffman tree: for a given probability distribution I need the Huffman tree to be identical regardless of permutations of the input data.

Here is a picture of what's happening vs what I want:

[image: Expectation vs reality]

Basically I want to know if it's possible to preserve the relative order of the items from the list to the tree. If not, why is that so?

For reference, I'm using the Huffman tree to generate sub groups according to a division of probability, so that I can run the search() procedure below. Notice that the data in the merge() sub-routine is combined, along with the weight. The codewords themselves aren't as important as the tree (which should preserve the relative order).

For example if I generate the following Huffman codes:

```
probabilities = [0.30, 0.25, 0.20, 0.15, 0.10]
items = ['a','b','c','d','e']
items = zip(items, probabilities)
t = encode(items)
d,l = hi.search(t)
print(d)
```

Using the following Class:

```
class Node(object):
    left = None
    right = None
    weight = None
    data = None
    code = None

    def __init__(self, w,d):
        self.weight = w
        self.data = d

    def set_children(self, ln, rn):
        self.left = ln
        self.right = rn

    def __repr__(self):
        return "[%s,%s,(%s),(%s)]" %(self.data,self.code,self.left,self.right)

    def __cmp__(self, a):
        return cmp(self.weight, a.weight)

    def merge(self, other):
        total_freq = self.weight + other.weight
        new_data = self.data + other.data
        return Node(total_freq,new_data)

    def index(self, node):
        return node.weight

def encode(symbfreq):
    pdb.set_trace()
    tree = [Node(sym,wt) for wt,sym in symbfreq]
    heapify(tree)
    while len(tree)>1:
        lo, hi = heappop(tree), heappop(tree)
        n = lo.merge(hi)
        n.set_children(lo, hi)
        heappush(tree, n)
    tree = tree[0]

    def assign_code(node, code):
        if node is not None:
            node.code = code
        if isinstance(node, Node):
            assign_code(node.left, code+'0')
            assign_code(node.right, code+'1')

    assign_code(tree, '')
    return tree
```

I get:

```
'a'->11
'b'->01
'c'->00
'd'->101
'e'->100
```

However, an assumption I've made in the search algorithm is that more probable items get pushed toward the left: that is I need 'a' to have the '00' codeword - and this should always be the case regardless of any permutation of the 'abcde' sequence. An example output is:

```
codewords = {'a':'00', 'b':'01', 'c':'10', 'd':'110', 'e':111'}
```

(N.b even though the codeword for 'c' is a suffix for 'd' this is ok).

For completeness, here is the search algorithm:

```
def search(tree):
    print(tree)
    pdb.set_trace()
    current = tree.left
    other = tree.right
    loops = 0
    while current:
        loops+=1
        print(current)
        if current.data != 0 and current is not None and other is not None:
            previous = current
            current = current.left
            other = previous.right
        else:
            previous = other
            current = other.left
            other = other.right
    return previous, loops
```

It works by searching for the 'leftmost' 1 in a group of 0s and 1s - the Huffman tree has to put more probable items on the left. For example if I use the probabilities above and the input:

```
items = [1,0,1,0,0]
```

Then the index of the item returned by the algorithm is 2 - which isn't what should be returned (0 should, as it's leftmost).

Comment: The tree you drew for what you're getting is not what you're getting.  E.g. the tree on the left shows 111 for `d`, but you are getting 101 for `d`.

Comment: @MarkAdler, sorry yes. I've been staring at this for 3 days, and can't tell up from down at the moment. Will you forgive a little slip up?

Comment: Your sample code has `t = hi.encode(items)` early on, but `hi` isn't defined.  What is it?

Comment: BTW, you took things away from the code I gave you before that would have been *very* helpful now:  distinguishing between `Symbol` nodes and artificial (internal) Huffman nodes, and a dict mapping a symbol name to its `Symbol` node.  Having both would make what you want *now* more-or-less straightforward.

Comment: @TimPeters sorry, it should read t = encode(items)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll flesh out what Mark Adler said with working code.  Everything he said is right :-)  The high points:

1. You must not use floating-point weights, or any other scheme that loses information about weights.  Use integers.  Simple and correct.  If, e.g., you have 3-digit floating probabilities, convert each to an integer via `int(round(the_probability * 1000))`, then maybe fiddle them to ensure the sum is exactly 1000.
2. `heapq` heaps are not "stable":  nothing is defined about which item is popped if multiple items have the same minimal weight.
3. So you can't get what you want *while* building the tree.
4. A small variation of "canonical Huffman codes" appears to be what you *do* want.  Constructing a tree for that is a long-winded process, but each step is straightforward enough.  The first tree built is thrown away:  the only information taken from it is the *lengths* of the codes assigned to each symbol.

Running:

```
syms = ['a','b','c','d','e']
weights = [30, 25, 20, 15, 10]
t = encode(syms, weights)
print t
```

prints this (formatted for readability):

```
[abcde,,
    ([ab,0,
        ([a,00,(None),(None)]),
        ([b,01,(None),(None)])]),
    ([cde,1,
        ([c,10,(None),(None)]),
        ([de,11,
            ([d,110,(None),(None)]),
            ([e,111,(None),(None)])])])]
```

Best I understand, that's exactly what you want.  Complain if it isn't ;-)

**EDIT**:  there was a bug in the assignment of canonical codes, which didn't show up unless weights were very different; fixed it.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data=None, weight=None,
                       left=None, right=None,
                       code=None):
        self.data = data
        self.weight = weight
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.code = code

    def is_symbol(self):
        return self.left is self.right is None

    def __repr__(self):
        return "[%s,%s,(%s),(%s)]" % (self.data,
                                      self.code,
                                      self.left,
                                      self.right)

    def __cmp__(self, a):
        return cmp(self.weight, a.weight)

def encode(syms, weights):
    from heapq import heapify, heappush, heappop

    tree = [Node(data=s, weight=w)
            for s, w in zip(syms, weights)]
    sym2node = {s.data: s for s in tree}
    heapify(tree)
    while len(tree) > 1:
        a, b = heappop(tree), heappop(tree)
        heappush(tree, Node(weight=a.weight + b.weight,
                            left=a, right=b))

    # Compute code lengths for the canonical coding.
    sym2len = {}
    def assign_codelen(node, codelen):
        if node is not None:
            if node.is_symbol():
                sym2len[node.data] = codelen
            else:
                assign_codelen(node.left, codelen + 1)
                assign_codelen(node.right, codelen + 1)
    assign_codelen(tree[0], 0)

    # Create canonical codes, but with a twist:  instead
    # of ordering symbols alphabetically, order them by
    # their position in the `syms` list.
    # Construct a list of (codelen, index, symbol) triples.
    # `index` breaks ties so that symbols with the same
    # code length retain their original ordering.
    triples = [(sym2len[name], i, name)
                for i, name in enumerate(syms)]
    code = oldcodelen = 0
    for codelen, _, name in sorted(triples):
        if codelen > oldcodelen:
            code <<= (codelen - oldcodelen)
        sym2node[name].code = format(code, "0%db" % codelen)
        code += 1
        oldcodelen = codelen

    # Create a tree corresponding to the new codes.
    tree = Node(code="")
    dir2attr = {"0": "left", "1": "right"}
    for snode in sym2node.values():
        scode = snode.code
        codesofar = ""
        parent = tree
        # Walk the tree creating any needed interior nodes.
        for d in scode:
            assert parent is not None
            codesofar += d
            attr = dir2attr[d]
            child = getattr(parent, attr)
            if codesofar == scode:
                # We're at the leaf position.
                assert child is None
                setattr(parent, attr, snode)
            elif child is not None:
                assert child.code == codesofar
            else:
                child = Node(code=codesofar)
                setattr(parent, attr, child)
            parent = child

    # Finally, paste the `data` attributes together up
    # the tree.  Why?  Don't know ;-)
    def paste(node):
        if node is None:
            return ""
        elif node.is_symbol():
            return node.data
        else:
            result = paste(node.left) + paste(node.right)
            node.data = result
            return result
    paste(tree)

    return tree
```

### Duplicate symbols

> Could I swap the sym2node dict to an ordereddict to deal with
>   repeated 'a'/'b's etc?

No, and for two reasons:

1. No mapping type supports duplicate keys; and,
2. The *concept* of "duplicate symbols" makes no sense for Huffman encoding.

So, if you're determined ;-) to pursue this, first you have to ensure that symbols are unique.  Just add this line at the start of the function:

```
        syms = list(enumerate(syms))
```

For example, if the `syms` passed in is:

```
['a', 'b', 'a']
```

that will change to:

```
[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'a')]
```

All symbols are now 2-tuples, and are obviously unique since each starts with a unique integer.  The only thing the *algorithm* cares about is that symbols can be used as dict keys; it couldn't care less whether they're strings, tuples, or any other hashable type that supports equality testing.

So nothing in the algorithm needs to change.  But before the end, we'll want to restore the original symbols.  Just insert this before the `paste()` function:

```
    def restore_syms(node):
        if node is None:
            return
        elif node.is_symbol():
            node.data = node.data[1]
        else:
            restore_syms(node.left)
            restore_syms(node.right)
    restore_syms(tree)
```

That simply walks the tree and strips the leading integers off the symbols' `.data` members.  Or, perhaps simpler, just iterate over `sym2node.values()`, and transform the `.data` member of each.

Comment: I'm not at my computer at the moment but I'll test this this weekend. Thank you ever so much.

Comment: this is exactly what I needed, thanks ever so much! Could I swap the sym2node dict to an ordereddict to deal with repeated 'a'/'b's etc?

Answer (score 3):

The usual practice is to use Huffman's algorithm only to generate the code lengths.  Then a canonical process is used to generate the codes from the lengths.  The tree is discarded.  Codes are assigned in order from shorter codes to longer codes, and within a code, the symbols are sorted.  This gives the codes you are expecting, `a = 00`, `b = 01`, etc.  This is called a [Canonical Huffman code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_Huffman_code).

The main reason this is done is to make the transmission of the Huffman code more compact.  Instead of sending the code for each symbol along with the compressed data, you only need to send the code length for each symbol.  Then the codes can be reconstructed on the other end for decompression.

A Huffman tree is not normally used for decoding either.  With a canonical code, simple comparisons to determine the length of the next code, and an index using the code value will take you directly to the symbol.  Or a table-driven approach can avoid the search for the length.

As for your tree, there are arbitrary choices being made when there are equal frequencies.  In particular, on the second step the first node pulled is `c` with probability 0.2, and the second node pulled is `b`  with probability 0.25.  However it would have been equally valid to pull, instead of `b`, the node that was made in the first step, `(e,d)`, whose probability is *also* 0.25.  In fact that is what you'd prefer for your desired end state.  Alas, you have relinquished the control of that arbitrary choice to the `heapq` library.

(Note: since you are using floating point values, 0.1 + 0.15 is not necessarily exactly equal to 0.25.  Though it turns out it is.  As another example, 0.1 + 0.2 is *not* equal to 0.3.  You would be better off using integers for the frequencies if you want to see what happens when sums of frequencies are equal to other frequencies or sums of frequencies.  E.g. 6,5,4,3,2.)

Some of the wrong ordering can be fixed by fixing some mistakes: change `lo.merge(high)` to `hi.merge(lo)`, and reverse the order of the bits to: `assign_code(node.left, code+'1')` followed by `assign_code(node.right, code+'0')`.  Then at least `a` gets assigned 00 and `d` is before `e` and `b` is before `c`.  The ordering is then `adebc`.

Now that I think about it, even if you pick `(e,d)` over `b`, e.g by setting the probability of `b` to 0.251, you still don't get the complete order that you're after.  No matter what, the probability of `(e,d)` (0.25) is greater than the probability of `c` (0.2).  So even in that case, the final ordering would be (with the fixes above) `abdec` instead of your desired `abcde`.  So it *is not possible* to get what you want assuming a consistent tree ordering and bit assignment with respect to the probabilities of groups of symbols.  E.g., assuming that for each branch the stuff on the left has a greater or equal probability than the stuff on the right, and 0 is always assigned to left and 1 is always assigned to right.  You would need to do something different.

The different thing that comes to mind is what I said at the start of the answer.  Use the Huffman algorithm just to get the code lengths.  Then you can assign the codes to the symbols in whatever order you like, and build a new tree.  That would be much easier than trying to come up with some sort of scheme to coerce the original tree to be what you want, and proving that that works in all cases.

Comment: I'm not really interested in the codes per se: it's the tree I'm using to search. It's really important that leftmost items in the original list are mapped to leftmost items in the tree.

Comment: My point is that you don't need the tree in the first place.  Why do you care about the tree?  What is it exactly that makes it "really important"?

Comment: I care, because I'm using it to encode groups of items to perform property testing on, based on their relative probabilities. The algorithm only gives the correct answer if the relative position of the items is preserved when mapped from a list to a tree. I've given the algorithm for searching the tree int he question.